# PostgreSQL count in calendar week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to use PostgreSQL to count the occurrences of something in the past calendar week (Monday through present day).  I have tried a few different things, currently I am looking at using `EXTRACT dow` to return the day of the week however this will return the same value for something that happened this Tuesday or last Tuesday.

```
SELECT COUNT(date_mastered) FROM words WHERE  date_mastered EXTRACT dow >0;
```

If any one can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `date_trunc()`?

```
SELECT COUNT(date_mastered)
FROM words
WHERE date_trunc('week', date_mastered) = date_trunc('week', now());
```

Actually, I think a better practice is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM words
WHERE date_mastered >= date_trunc('week', now());
```

This assumes no future dates, but it allows the use of an index on `date_mastered)`.

Comment: This looks like it will work.  I am a little confused how date mastered (yyyy-mm-dd) can be compared to date_trunc('week',now())

Comment: @user8735495 . . . I am assuming that `date_mastered` is stored as a `date`.  That makes the most sense.

Comment: yes date_mastered is stored as a date.  What I am unclear about is how `date_trunc('week',now())` return the date of the most recent Sunday.